# Loading Tensorflow model file not found

Tags: python, path

I saved my tensorflow model like this:

```
model.save('static/mysite/saved_model_weights/' + symbols[i] + ' saved model')
```

Where `symbols[i]` is just a string such as `'AAPL'` because I am saving multiple models.

but when I want to load model like:

```
loaded_model = load_model('static/mysite/saved_model_weights/AAPL saved model')
```

I get the error:

> OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: static/mysite/saved_model_weights/AAPL saved model/saved_model.pb{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

I am calling `load_model()` from a different script, but the files are stored before I call it and the files are present in the correct directory. The saved model is a directory (with Tensorflow's SavedModel format) containing:

- `assets` folder: (empty) variables folder
- `keras_metadata.pb`
- `saved_model.pb` (which is called by the `load_model()` function).

link to the Tensorflow documentary on saving models- https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

Comment: Please add the original code you have written here: `model.save('path/model')` and `load_model('path/model')`

Comment: @Kaveh I have included the specific code, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by using the absolute path with backslashes '' instead of forwards ones '/' and putting the letter 'r' before the path to indicate a raw string rather than a normal one. it ended up looking like this:     `loaded_model = load_model(r'C:\Users\Mason Choi\django_market_predict\mysite\static\mysite\saved_model_weights\AAPL_saved_model')`

Comment: I believe you can update the question since it actually is not specific to Tensorflow. This is  a path problem and could have happened if you worked with other DL librairies or more broadly if you wanted to read any file.